# Limit of internet speed over air medium calculation?

Tags: internet

What is the maximum internet possible limit via air medium.How do we calucate maximum speed limit of data transfer via air .

Is there any formula for this ?

Comment: You mean like...if we used the entire EM spectrum just for your one internet connection?

Comment: SNR affects Bits/symbol and protocol BW. class B is better for range N etc is better for bandwidth compression.

Comment: @DKNguyen any spectrum over air is fine what is the limit of internet speed .

Comment: -46dBm 866Mbps 11AC_VHT80 Ch 36 80MHz on WiFi

Comment: @AmruthA You are getting weird answers because to an EE your question makes little sense. It is like asking "how many different products can a supermarket sell?". Or "how many leaves do plants grow?". These questions don't make sense, as they lack additional parameters. I.e. During a week and on a area of 100 sqare metres or something like that. You can't see what information is missing, because you lack basic knowledge about signal transmission. Something which is taught during two or four semesters of EE. There are dozens of formulas!

Answer (score 4):

It’s limited by the same criteria as any medium: Shannon’s information theorem. Basically, bandwidth * SNR.

More precisely, the Shannon-Hartley Equation:

- \$ C = B \; log_2 \left( 1 + \frac{S}{N}\right)  \;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\; \rightarrow (1)\$

Where \$B\$ is bandwidth in Hz, \$\frac{S}{N}\$ is the signal-to-noise ratio.

As a practical example, under the right conditions, 802.11ac can achieve over a Gbit of bandwidth using an 80MHz channel.